# How do cilia beat?

Tags: molecular-biology

From what I have learnt, the mechanism of the beating of cilia is: movement of dynein towards the (-)-end i.e. towards the microtubule-organizing center (MTOC), causing the 2 pairs of microtubules to (supposedly) slide. This is prevented by linker proteins anchored in the adjacent pairs of microtubules. Therefore, when dyneins move, the linker proteins become skewed hence and bending of cilia.

My question is: As far as I know, dynein can only move in one direction (towards (-)-end) i.e. the cilia can only move in one direction, which is forward beating action. I would like to ask how can the cilia move back to the original position (backward movement) and initiate the next beating?

Edit: I have checked [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cilium#Structure), it says there is a process called intraflagellar transport (IFT), which is **bi-directional** and allows the retrograde transport of cilia (backward movement?) by dyneins, which seems contradictory to what I have learnt, so how can this process actually happen?

[image]